# Is it guaranteed that a callback passed to the always function will be called after the function(data) callback finished its work

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

Is it guaranteed that a callback passed to the `always` function will be called after the `function(data)` callback finished its work?

```
$.get(link, function(data) {
    // Do some stuff
}).always(function() {
    // Will this callback be called after "do some stuff" finished its work?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that true it should, check example bellow from **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)** :

```js
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" ) 
.done(function() { 
  alert( "success" );
}) 
.fail(function() { 
  alert( "error" );
}) 
.always(function() { 
  alert( "complete" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```